# Trying to prove that for a ring $R$ with identity, $R^2 = R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove that if a ring $R$ has an identity, then $R^2 = R$.

Honesty I don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Eric

Comment: First, write down the definition of $R^2$.

Comment: It is clear that $R^2\subseteq R$. Show that if there is an identity then $R\subseteq R^2$, since $r=1\cdot r$.

Comment: What is the definition of $R^2$ you are using? The set of all pairwise products between two elements in $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R^2 \subseteq R$ since $R$ is closed under multiplication.
On the other hand $R=R\cdot 1 \subseteq R^2$.